# How to 301 redirect piece by piece?

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect, redirection

I will move my blog website (monthly traffic of 250k) to a new domain name. I will use HTTP 301 redirections.

But I should not redirect all links at the same time because of some business reasons. I should redirect them piece by piece like 50 pages daily (I have 1100 links).

However in this scenario, everyday I’m going to write 50 urls to nginx configuration file. Even 50 urls looks bad and crowded to me. I can’t image how I will handle 700-800 urls in the nginx configuration file. All links include keywords.

How can I handle this problem? What is the best practice?

Thanks !

Comment: Use regular expressions, if possible - perhaps by folder? Otherwise just create 800 redirect rules, it'll work fine.

Comment: i plan to make a redirection file and include it to nginx file. Can this big file cause a nginx bottleneck ( slow running ) problem ?

Comment: One you hit millions of redirects it could be an issue - [read this](http://www.agileweboperations.com/supporting-millions-of-pretty-url-rewrites-in-nginx-with-lua-and-redis).

Comment: Also [read this](https://serverfault.com/questions/191088/how-many-nginx-redirects-is-too-many) - you won't have a problem with Nginx.